# Starting a program in a running rdp-terminal-server (W2008R2) session with full control over the server but no control over the client?

Tags: windows, terminal, session

I have full control over a Windows 2008 R2 server. A mobile client runs a windows terminal session on the server over RDP and WLAN. Its connection and session are currently active.

Now I would like to launch a program within this session from the server. I have no access to the client and I cannot disconnect the client first.

The reason is: The client device is lost in a high-bay-stock area and I want it to beep, so I can find it. The battery will last for around three more hours.

How can I "inject" my beep-program into its running terminal session?